# Oracle NoSQL Connection Pool and transaction management

Tags: java, oracle, java-ee-8, oracle-nosql

There is any implementations of connection pool or transaction management on oracle nosql 19 database (Key-Value Paier)?
I want to use this database on my JavaEE 8 project.
but can not understand :

- How this database managed connection pool ?
- How can manage transactions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mah454 There is no connection pool concept in the Oracle NoSQL Database interface; nor is one necessary.

The usage model is that a user opens/creates a KVStore instance which will connect to appropriate server nodes as requests are made. A single KVStore instance is intended to be shared in a multithreaded application and handles all connections to server nodes internally.

Regarding Transactions

The short answer is that you can perform KVStore.execute operations:

execute(List operations) (see execute)

Operations on records with the same shard (major) key, but different primary(minor) keys will be wrapped in an ACID transaction. All other single-record operations are in effect "auto-commit" transactions. You can perform CAS/RMW style operations using putIfVersion and deleteIfVersion.

Does this answer your question?